# Why does my kitchen sink shut off as soon as I turn it on?

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture

When I turn my faucet on, it shuts off but if I turn it on low it stays on. If I turn the water on to high or activate the spray nozzle, it will stop flowing.  Why?

The faucet is a Pfister Avalon 26 series.

I have changed the 974-0740 cartridge and the faucet aerator.

Comment: Something, somewhere in the pipes is normally freely or flexed away from a junction, but when the flow is high enough it gets pulled into a position where it blocks most of the flow as if it was a check valve. If _only_ the sink is affected, I'd start from there and work backward trying to find where that think is occurring The only guess I've got is that maybe the deflector valve that send water to the spray hose is being oversensitive and cutting off flow to the tap even when the spray hose is not drawing enough flow that you're noticing it...

Comment: does it happens with hot and cold

Comment: Try without the aerator

Comment: I think @keshlam is onto something - I'd look into issues with the spray nozzle. Sounds like the [diverter](https://www.amazon.com/Pfister-9510390-Marielle-Treviso-Diverter/dp/B004PUFJ5C?th=1) (Amazon link) may be bad. It's probably a cheap enough part to try throwing one at it to see if it works. *Definitions of "cheap enough" may vary, YMMV.

Comment: Diverter, not deflector -- thanks for the correction; wasn't remembering the proper term.

Comment: Maybe there's some debris inside, and high pressure just forces it against the aperture, but low pressure still allows some water by?